# c# Selenium Chromedriver opens wrong url onload

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, html-agility-pack

I'm using Selenium with chromedriver to scrape a list of data using HTML agility pack but when I try to navigate to this page, the url gets changed from [url1](https://www.crimereports.com/home/#!/dashboard?incident_types=Assault%252CAssault%2520with%2520Deadly%2520Weapon%252CBreaking%2520%2526%2520Entering%252CDisorder%252CDrugs%252CHomicide%252CKidnapping%252CLiquor%252COther%2520Sexual%2520Offense%252CProperty%2520Crime%252CProperty%2520Crime%2520Commercial%252CProperty%2520Crime%2520Residential%252CQuality%2520of%2520Life%252CRobbery%252CSexual%2520Assault%252CSexual%2520Offense%252CTheft%252CTheft%2520from%2520Vehicle%252CTheft%2520of%2520Vehicle&start_date=2019-01-26&end_date=2019-02-09&days=sunday%252Cmonday%252Ctuesday%252Cwednesday%252Cthursday%252Cfriday%252Csaturday&start_time=0&end_time=23&include_sex_offenders=false&lat=39.0178789&lng=-77.1233838&zoom=14&current_tab=list&shapeIds=) to [url2](https://www.crimereports.com/home/#!/dashboard?incident_types=Assault%252CAssault%2520with%2520Deadly%2520Weapon%252CBreaking%2520%2526%2520Entering%252CDisorder%252CDrugs%252CHomicide%252CKidnapping%252CLiquor%252COther%2520Sexual%2520Offense%252CProper&start_date=2019-01-31&end_date=2019-02-14&days=sunday%252Cmonday%252Ctuesday%252Cwednesday%252Cthursday%252Cfriday%252Csaturday&start_time=0&end_time=23&include_sex_offenders=false&lat=39&lng=-95&zoom=3&current_tab=map&shapeIds=). Therefore is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
 string url = "";
 Console.WriteLine("Web Crawler!");

 Console.WriteLine("Enter URL :");
 url = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine("Entered URL :" + url);

 // selenium section
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2);
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(".", chromeOptions);
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: It changes in navigation? you insert the first url and the second one is opened?

Comment: Yah I guess it changes in the navigation.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Check if it happen when the url is hard-coded in the program instead of input.

Comment: Oh yeah, it works when it's hard-coded. Know anyway to overcome this issue?

Comment: You could put the url in CSV file and read it,

Comment: Yah it could work. Post a complete answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer. By the way thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url might not being passed correctly from the CMD. Instead, you can read it from a CSV file

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("csvFile"))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    string url = string.Empty;
    while (!parser.EndOfData) 
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        url = fields[0];
    }
}
```